# Chromium incorrectly includes Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site in stylesheet request

Tags: chromium, content-security-policy, html-reports-jenkins

Problem: When a web server responds with the header

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

this appears to cause Chromium to add the header

```
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

when requesting the stylesheet from the same origin (and directory) as the containing html page. Instead, it is expected that the above CSP cause the browser to submit `Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin`.

To reproduce using nginx+Chromium:

Add the following 4 lines to a `location` directive in an nginx config file:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';";
if ($http_sec_fetch_site = 'cross-site') {
  return 403;
}
```

Serve the following 2 static files `report.html` and `report.css` from that location.

`report.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Report</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="report.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Report</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and

`report.css`:

```
body { font-family: sans-serif }
```

Here are screenshots of both the `report.html` and subsequent `report.css` requests with the Developer tools Network window:

[image]

[image]

Note that the request for `report.css` is `403 Forbidden` due to the incorrect `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` header in the request.

Question: Why is Chromium submitting `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` for a file that should be `same-origin` based on the given CSP which allows same-origin stylesheets?

Note: If it seems the issue is not being reproduced, verify that the following header is seen in the server response when `report.html` is requested:

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

in order to set the CSP for the subsequent request for `report.css`.

Chromium Version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)

Comment: Are you sure the first request origin is also `http://localhost` and not `http://127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Yes, good question. Added screenshots for the `report.html` and `report.css` requests for verification.

Comment: Got similar issues with Safari: Reports `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` on same-site

Comment: @Matt were you able to find a solution for this. I have a case where I make a request to the exact same domain/path and Chrome decides to treat it as `cross-site` for some reason.

Comment: @SRaghav Yes, it requires replacing `sandbox;` in the CSP server response w/ `sandbox allow-same-origin;`. In case you were encountering this issue in Jenkins (as I was) they should have a fix for it in version 2.417.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. would you like to convert the above comment to an answer? Also in my case Chrome returned same-site/cross-site randomly and apparently it may be somehow related to the limit on header size on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a misconfiguration on the server side. The header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

is actually self-contradictory. The directives `default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';` attempt to allow `same-origin` images and stylesheets. However, `sandbox` without `allow-same-origin` causes resources to fail the `same-origin` policy:

> `allow-same-origin`
>
> If this token is not used, the resource is treated as being from a special origin that always fails the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Same-origin_policy) (potentially preventing access to [data storage/cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_data_storage_access) and some JavaScript APIs).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox

Thus the most secure adjustment to be made in order to keep `sandbox` and only allow images and stylesheets to be served from the same origin is to add `allow-same-origin` to the `sandbox` directive:

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-same-origin; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

For anyone encountering this problem in Jenkins, a [fix](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-71366) is expected to be released in Jenkins 2.417.

Other workarounds have recently been updated with this information on https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/